# Dragging a borderless form to a negative location

Tags: c#, winforms

When dragging a borderless form to the top of the screen; if the Y coordinate is negative, it sets it back to 0. What I'm looking to do is be able to drag the form above the top, where the Y coordinate would be negative, the same way you can with every other side of the screen.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public partial class BorderlessForm : Form
{
    public BorderlessForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _isNegative;
    private Point _negative;

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isNegative) {
            Location = _negative;
        }
        //base.OnResizeEnd(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Location.Y < 0) {
            _isNegative = true;
            _negative = Location;

        }
        else {
            _isNegative = false;
        }
        //base.OnMove(e);
    }
}
```

This was the best I could come up with after thinking on it for a while. The problem is that when the mouse is released and the form is finished moving, `OnMove` is called before `OnResizeEnd`, and `_isNegative` is then set back to false. At least, that is what I assume is happening.

Do I have the right idea, or is there some better way to go about this?

Comment: You can use a flag to prevent onmove statements!

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I can't move any window top of the top.

Comment: Did you subscribe to the `OnMouseMove()` event somewhere? That's where you move the Form, based on the mouse movement offset you registered in the `OnMouseDown()` event. You'ld also need verify that the Left Button is pressed.

Comment: @Jimi That SendMessage takes care of it for you.  It mimics pressing down on the title bar of a form.

Comment: Just try this with a regular window, say Notepad's.  Press Alt+Space > M and keep hitting the up arrow.  That is what your window does as well.  Just Windows helping to keep the user out of trouble.  That can be changed, override the handling of [this message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo) with WinProc().

Comment: @ LarsTech   Yep, a left out (or deleted) a piece. **Without PInvoking** (the concept got lost), you can use the `MouseMove` event, with the offset position registered in `MouseDown`, to *drag* (set the Location) the Form wherever you want, no questions asked.

Answer (score 0):

So, I thought more about what [isaeid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3703127/isaeid) said, and was able to come up with a solution. Still not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but here it is:

```
public partial class ImageForm : PerPixelAlphaForm
{
    public ImageForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _isNegative;
    private Point _negative;
    private bool _flag;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            NativeMethods.ReleaseCapture();
            NativeMethods.SendMessage(Handle, NativeMethods.WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, NativeMethods.HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isNegative) {
            Location = _negative;
            _isNegative = false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Location.Y < 0) {
            _isNegative = true;
            _flag = true;
            _negative = Location;
        }
        else {
            if (_flag) {
                _flag = false;
                return;
            }
            _isNegative = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change some events like this:

```
protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isNegative)
            {
                Location = _negative;
            }
            oldRight = this.Right;
            oldBottom = this.Bottom;
            //base.OnResizeEnd(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
        {
            if ( this.Right == oldRight || this.Bottom == oldBottom)
                return;
            if (Location.Y < 0)
            {
                _isNegative = true;
                _negative = Location;

            }
            else
            {
                _isNegative = false;
            }
            //base.OnMove(e);


        }
```

When top or left of window is changed, dotnet determines location of window is changed and calls onmove event, i consider if right or bottom of the window is not changed so window's location is not changed.

Add this codes too:

```
int oldBottom, oldRight;
    private void BorderlessForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        oldRight = this.Right;
        oldBottom = this.Bottom;
    }
```